# Could not find the GDAL library (connection with Hana)

Tags: python, django, hana

I am using Python 3.8.5 version and the Django 3.2.4. I already install GDAL library from the official website with the version 3.3.0. with a pip install.

There are 4 databases presents at the origin in Django but I have to use the Hana one which is notpython. I have only found 2 topics relative to that on GitHub but they are both very old (4 years and 8 years ago).
I have tried everything to solve that problem but nothing seems to work. I already have the following message when I try to make migrations :

"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal302", "gdal301", "gdal300", "gdal204", "gdal203", "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings."

Someone has an idea to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

django don't use gdal python binding. It only require the share library `libgdal.so`, so you need to have `libgdal.so` installed somewhere on your system.

Next if gdal is not installed in system directory (ie installed with your distribution package manager), django most of the time is not able to find it, even if the path is in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

You have to configure it explicitly in the django settings, as well as [`geos`](https://www.osgeo.org/projects/geos/) which is also required:

```py
# django settings of your project
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = "/custom/install/prefix/lib/libgeos_c.so"
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "/custom/install/prefix/lib/libgdal.so"
```

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/